# Sampling size determination for small probabilities

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, quality-control

I am not sure I could find a clear answer on a correct formula for sampling size determination for finding rare events. Specifically I need to be 99% sure, that failure rate of certain population is below 5%. It is not that important to know what the failure rate is, but it is just important to know that it is below 5% How do I select the sampling size?

Straightforward answer would be to use such formula:

http://www.macorr.com/sample-size-methodology.htm

This formula, as I understand, is coming from the work of Cochran (ref [1], paragraph 4.4).

**Q1: So, is this a right formula to use in my case?**

**Q2: Sampling size**
Suppose this is a right formula, then It looks like, the needed sampling size reduces if the  p (probability of event) deviates from 0,5. This is because p is included in the formula as p(1-p), which has a maximum as 0,5. Somehow I do not grasp the logic bind this, as surely to detect a rare event one need to collect more samples. Or am I missing something here?  My concerns are also sort of shared in this article :

http://www.kck.usm.my/ppsg/aos/Vol_1/09_14_Ayub.pdf, where authors express opinion that the formula is only applicable for P in the interval between 0,1 and 0,9 and that for rare events it shall raise significantly, however I understand this is just an opinion of this authors, because Cochran is his book writes, that using 50% for P is a conservative estimate and then gives example “If P seems likely to lie between 5 and 9%, for instance, we assume 9% for the estimation of n” (ref [1], par. 4.4.). Thus he implicitly suggests, that the formula is also applicable for values of P as low as 6% (which  is pretty much my case).

**Q3 Confidence interval.** 
Since the value C (confidence interval) comes in a form of +-, then what shall be the confidence interval in my case? Is it correctly to say, that if I want to be 99% sure that failure rate is below 5%, this is equivalent of saying, that I want to be 99% sure, that failure rate is 2,5 % with the Confidence interval of 2,5%. ?

[1] Sampling Techniques, third edition. William G. Cochran. 1977. John Wiley and Sons.